# IP address from ISP

Tags: networking, routing, nat, isp

I am learning about routers and PAT right now. I am thinking about my public address assigned to my home router. Is it possible that ISP didn't provide real public address for me but instead it gave me an address being a result of PAT? To simplify a question: is PAT on multiple intermediate rotuers possible? What about the limit of number of IPv4 public addresses?

Comment: You should read [Carrier Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible that ISP didn't provide real public address for me but instead it gave me an address being a result of PAT?

Yes. Many ISPs now use Carrier-Grade NAT (although there are still many which don't).

For example, if your router shows that its ISP-assigned address is from the private 100.64.0.0/10 range, that's definitely an indication of CGNAT.

> is PAT on multiple intermediate rotuers possible?

It is. To the outside, NATed packets are indistinguishable from normal ones – they can be NATed again in the same way. There are many real-world examples of double or even triple NAT occuring accidentally and intentionally.

Comment: (For example: You are behind CGNAT. Your home router implements NAT. You "extend wifi" using a 2nd router, which is not in bridge mode, so it implements NAT again. You use your phone's "USB tethering" to connect a computer to Wi-Fi. That's four layers of NAT! None of the layers realizes that it's applying NAT to an already-NATed packet.)

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible that ISP didn't provide real public address

If ISP use Carrier-grade NAT (CGN), you'all receive an address that  is not a pb for standard usage (web, mail) but you'll not be able to host your servers, ...

> it gave me an address being a result of PAT

Some ISP supply only IP with only a range of ports (and not fixed public IP). Except if you receive the first range of port, as previous point you'll not be able to host your servers.

You have to see theirs offers or ask to be clear on that point and/or use IPV6.